# Cannot add foreign key constraint with foreign key being primary

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I am getting the

```
Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.172 sec
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I made sure that the foreign key is a primary key. 
My sql:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
StudentID INT(6) NOT NULL,
StudName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
StudEmail VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
StudeHomeNum INT(10) NOT NULL,
StudCellPhoneNum INT(10) NOT NULL,
CourseCode INT(6) NOT NULL,
ProgramCode INT(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (StudentID),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseCode)
    REFERENCES Course (CourseCode)
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
CourseCode INT(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
CourseName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Prequisites VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `CourseCode` code column in `Student` table is referencing `Course` table, you have to create `Course` table first. Change your sql code as below

```
CREATE TABLE Course (
CourseCode INT(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
CourseName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Prequisites VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Student (
StudentID INT(6) NOT NULL,
StudName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
StudEmail VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
StudeHomeNum INT(10) NOT NULL,
StudCellPhoneNum INT(10) NOT NULL,
CourseCode INT(6) NOT NULL,
ProgramCode INT(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (StudentID),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseCode)
    REFERENCES Course (CourseCode)
);
```